# Android - How to show images from SDcard android Use ImageGetter

Tags: java, android, html

Hi guys i have problem i need show image in EditText use : ImageGetter.
this work

```
String html = "<img src=\"ic_launcher\">";
    CharSequence text = Html.fromHtml(html, new Html.ImageGetter(){
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
            int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            d.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);

            return d;
        }
    }, null);

    mContentEditText.setText(text);
```

but i need my image in SDcard ,not "R.drawable.IMAGE_NAME" ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String html2 = "<img src=\"a.jpg\">";
    CharSequence text2 = Html.fromHtml(html2, new Html.ImageGetter(){
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
            String path = "/sdcard/a/" + source;
            File f = new File(path);
            Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
            bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return bmp;
        }
    }, null);
    display.setText(text2);
```

is Work for me! 100% thx all :)

Comment: how get multiple images? , what if the html2 has two image src ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the appropriate permissions in the manifest so that you can read from external storage. Then create a piece of code that will search your SD Card for the image you want.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Where imageFile is your ImageFile, for example: `File imageFile = new File("/sdcard/gallery_photo_4.jpg");`

Comment: how to put here ?... String html = "<img src=\"ic_launcher\">";

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean.

Comment: how can we get multiple images from html images are in SD card?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

     mPath ="Your image Path here";
     l1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
     l1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     System.out.println(mPath);

         Bitmap b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath),l1.getWidth(),l1.getHeight(),false);
if(b!=null){

        ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageBitmap(b);
    l2.addView(iv);
    }


}
```

Here is the code which works for me.hope it will help you.

Comment: This isn't I want ...After all Thanks

Comment: i have put my own code.you can use Bitmap.decodeScaledBitmap(BitmapFoctory.decodeFile(mPath),width,height,filter); to get image from your SD card.it is what for you asked in question.

Comment: you can get your image path using
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"yourDirectory/yourImageName.png"

Comment: how can we get multiple images from html images are in SD card?